# Como funciona 'provides...with' e 'uses' no Java modular?

Tags: java, jigsaw

No Java 9, como resultado do projeto Jigsaw, ganhamos a capacidade de definir módulos. Os módulos são bem simples, mas ainda há 2 coisas que me deixam confuso neles, que é a utilização do `provides...with` e `uses`.

Ambos na documentação se referem ao uso de "serviços", que pelo que entendi são as interfaces e/ou classes abstratas. Um módulo que usa `provides...with` é um fornecedor de serviços, e um que usa `uses` é um consumidor de serviços.

Mas por que usar eles? E como usá-los? O `exports` e `requires` não são capazes de fazer o mesmo trabalho?

Comment: Os módulos do Java 9 vieram depois de **OSGi**. Principalmente o conceito de serviço em OSGi, que é bem próximo ao que é definido no Java 9. Agora em relação a sua pergunta, o motivo de `provides` e `uses` existirem, é para fazer o `ServiceLoader` trabalhar direito com módulos. Ver https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Comment: A resposta não responde ao "por que usar eles?" e "o exports e requires não são capazes de fazer o mesmo trabalho?", além disso, só minha opinião mesmo, melhora a tradução disso.

Answer (score 2):

## Módulo Exports

Um módulo Java deve exportar explicitamente todos os pacotes no módulo que devem estar acessíveis para outros módulos usando o módulo. Os pacotes exportados são declarados no [descritor do módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java). Aqui está como uma simples declaração de exportação é exibida dentro de um [descritor de módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java):

```
module com.jenkov.mymodule {
    exports com.jenkov.mymodule;
}
```

Este exemplo exporta o pacote chamado `com.jenkov.mymodule`.

Observe que somente o pacote listado é exportado. Nenhum "subpacote" do pacote exportado é exportado. Isso significa que, se o pacote mymodule contiver um subpacote chamado util, o pacote `com.jenkov.mymodule.util` **não será** exportado apenas porque o `com.jenkov.mymodule` é.

Para exportar um subpacote também, você deve declará-lo explicitamente no [descritor do módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java), assim:

```
module com.jenkov.mymodule {
    exports com.jenkov.mymodule;
    exports com.jenkov.mymodule.util;
}
```

Você não precisa exportar o pacote pai para exportar um subpacote. A seguinte declaração de exportação de [descritor de módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java) é perfeitamente válida:

```
module com.jenkov.mymodule {
    exports com.jenkov.mymodule.util;
}
```

Este exemplo exporta apenas o pacote `com.jenkov.mymodule.util` e não o pacote `com.jenkov.mymodule`.

## Módulo Requires

Se um módulo Java requer que outro módulo faça seu trabalho, esse outro módulo também deverá ser especificado no [descritor do módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java). Aqui está um exemplo de um Java module requires declaration:

```
module com.jenkov.mymodule {
    requires javafx.graphics;
}
```

Este exemplo de um [descritor de módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java) declara que requer o módulo Java padrão chamado `javafx.graphics`.

## Serviços

Um serviço consiste em duas partes principais:

1. Uma service interface (interface de serviço).
2. Uma ou mais service implementations (implementações de serviço).

A service interface geralmente está localizada em um módulo Java que contém apenas a service interface, além também de quaisquer classes e interfaces relacionadas à service interface.

As service implementations são fornecidas por módulos Java separados - não pelo módulo service interface. Normalmente, um módulo Java de service implementation conterá uma única implementação de serviço.

Um módulo ou aplicação Java pode exigir o módulo e o código da service interface, sem saber exatamente qual outro módulo entrega a service implementation. A service implementation é descoberta no tempo de execução e depende de quais módulos de service implementation estão disponíveis no caminho do módulo Java quando a aplicação é iniciada.

#### Módulo Service Interface

Os módulos da service interface Java não requerem uma declaração especial da interface de serviço. Você acabou de criar um módulo Java regular. Aqui está um exemplo de descritor de módulo de serviço Java:

```
module com.jenkov.myservice {
    exports com.jenkov.myservice
}
```

Observe como a service interface real não é mencionada. O módulo da service interface exporta apenas o pacote Java que contém a interface de serviço. A service interface é apenas uma interface Java normal, portanto, não mostrei um exemplo disso.

#### Módulo Service Implementation

Um módulo Java que deseja implementar uma service interface a partir de um módulo de service interface deve:

- Requerer o módulo da service interface em seu próprio [descritor de
  módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java).
- Implementar a service interface com uma classe Java.
- Declarar a implementação da service interface em seu [descritor de
  módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java).

Imagine que o módulo `com.jenkov.myservice` contenha uma interface chamada `com.jenkov.myservice.MyService`. Imagine também que você deseja criar um módulo de service implementation para essa interface de serviço. Imagine que sua implementação seja chamada `com.blabla.myservice.MyServiceImpl`. Para declarar a service implementation, o [descritor do módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java) para o módulo de service implementation teria a seguinte aparência:

```
module com.blabla.myservice {
    requires com.jenkov.myservice;

    provides com.jenkov.myservice.MyService with
       com.blabla.myservice.MyServiceImpl
}
```

O [descritor do módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java) primeiro declara que requer o módulo da interface de serviço. Segundo, o [descritor do módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java) declara que fornece uma implementação para a interface de serviço `com.jenkov.myservice.MyService` por meio da classe `com.blabla.myservice.MyServiceImpl`.

Agora que este módulo declara que implementa a interface de serviço, precisamos ver como um módulo Java pode procurar uma implementação da interface de serviço em tempo de execução.

#### Módulo Service Client

Depois de ter um módulo de service interface e um módulo de service implementation, você pode criar um módulo cliente que usa o serviço. Às vezes, um módulo service client (cliente de serviço) é chamado de módulo service consumer (consumidor de serviço) ou módulo service user (usuário de serviço), mas o significado é o mesmo - um módulo que usa um serviço especificado em um módulo externo e implementado por outro módulo externo.

Para usar o serviço, o módulo client (cliente) deve declarar em seu [descritor de módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java) que ele usa o serviço. Aqui está como declarar o uso de um serviço em um [descritor de módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java):

```
module com.client.myservicelient {
    requires com.jenkov.myservice;

    uses com.jenkov.myservice.MyService;
}
```

Observe como o [descritor do módulo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#module-descriptor-module-info.java) client (cliente) também declara que requer o módulo `com.jenkov.myservice` que contém a service interface. Não é necessário exigir os módulos de service implementation. Esses são pesquisados em tempo de execução. Somente o módulo da service interface deve ser necessário.

A vantagem de não ter que declarar os módulos de service implementation é que os módulos de implementação podem ser trocados sem quebrar o código do cliente. Você pode decidir qual service implementation usar ao montar a aplicação - soltando os módulos de implementação de serviço desejados no caminho do módulo. O módulo cliente e o módulo de interface de serviço são, portanto, dissociados dos módulos de implementação de serviço.

Agora, o módulo de service client (cliente de serviço) pode procurar uma implementação de interface de serviço em tempo de execução como esta:

```
Iterable<MyService> services =
         ServiceLoader.load(MyService.class);
```

O `Iterator` retornado contém uma lista de implementações da interface do `MyService`. De fato, ele conterá todas as implementações encontradas nos módulos encontrados no caminho do módulo. O módulo client (cliente) agora pode iterar o `Iterator` e encontrar a implementação de serviço que deseja usar.

## Bibliografia

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html